# Check if key in array has multi values by ternary

Tags: php, arrays

How to check if key in array has multi values like `array("id" => "5", "7", "10")` by ternary or something

I want check like this `$check = ($array > 1) ? "Yes" : "No";`

I know that will not work but only to understand what i mean,

If can't check by ternary, let me know any other method to check it

> FIXED

Comment: `$check = (is_array($array['id'])) ? "yes" : "no";`

Comment: not work for me

Comment: adapt to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong if you define the array as `array("id" => "5", "7", "10")` then you will have your array key value combination as

`[id] => 1 
[0] => 5 
[1] => 9`

only first element will have the key **id** and other will use numeric keys.

The Correct approach would be to create an array of values for a single key such as

`$array = array("id" => ["5", "7", "10"])`

now you can check as

`is_multi_valued = (count($array['id'])>1)?"yes":"no"`

> FIXED

Comment: in my code when use print_r; array id return like this 5,7,9 not [id] => 5 [0] => 7 ... so can't check with your method

Comment: not help me but i fixed it by myself so i accept your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    $array = [[1, 2, 3], ['c', 5], ['o', 7, [8, [9, 10, [11, 12, 13, 14, [15, 16, [17, 18, 19, [20]]]]]]]];

    $aFull = [];
    foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $item) {
        $aFull[] = $item;
    }
    var_dump(count($array) == count($aFull));
```